# How to link my program to a library that contains malloc and free [32-Bit ARM assembly] [raspbian]

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, 32-bit

I want to use malloc and free in my 32-bit ARM assembly program. The problem is that I don't how to link my program to the library that contains those two functions. I know the linker path for the 64-bit version but not the 32-bit one.

For 64-Bit ARM assembly, It would look like this...

ld -o project /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so project.o -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1

How would I do the same thing but for the 32-bit version?

Comment: `gcc -nostartfiles project.o` will run `ld` in a way that links the C library, with a correct `ld.so` ELF interpreter path.  Either `gcc -m32` or `arm-linux-gnu-gcc`.

Comment: No, it sounds like the OP is running a 64-bit operating system and trying to compile a 32-bit assembly program.  Plain old `gcc` would target the native architecture of the operating system (64-bit ARM).  Perhaps the OP needs to download a cross-compiler.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: Or they already have one but didn't know to run it.  That's why my first comment suggested that `arm-linux-gnu-gcc -nostartfiles project.o` might be the GCC they want to invoke.  (I also guessed that `gcc -m32 -nostartfiles` might work, but I assume that was wrong; even multiarch AArch64 systems wouldn't have a single `gcc` front-end that could make ARM32 vs. AArch64 with just a command-line option like i386 / x86-64 GCC does, or else cross-gcc would have that feature for ARM/AArch64.)